# TypeError: $.browser is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
        elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
        destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
        if ($.browser.safari) {
            $('body').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100);
        } else {
            $('html').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Хочу сделать переход якорю плавным.
Вот html:

```
 <header>
        <div class="butthead">
            <a href="#home" class="el1">home</a>
            <a class="el2" href="#">about</a>
            <a class="el3" href="#">support</a>
            <a class="el4" href="#">contact</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="page1" id="home">
        <div id="centered-text">
            <span class="typed1"></span>
            <h3 id="under">Web-site maked with HTML5, CSS3 and bit of JavaScript</h3>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Консоль выдает ошибку на строке  `if ($.browser.safari) {`

> TypeError: $.browser is undefined

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $.browser has been removed from JQuery 1.9. You can to use Modernizr project instead

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798403/typeerror-browser-is-undefined